# How to show unique row with corresponding other column max value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch max column value by grouping other column. I am almost near but stuck at last point. Here is me code

TABLE:

```
      id . sys_id        . renewal
      1  . aaad00101     . 0
      2  . aaad00101     . 1
      3  . aaad00104     . 0
      4  . aaad00102     . 0
      5  . aaad00101     . 2
      6  . aaad00103     . 0
```

SQL Query:

```
     "SELECT * FROM $company WHERE renewal IN (SELECT DISTINCT
      MAX(renewal)FROM $company GROUP BY sys_id) ORDER BY sys_id"
```

Result:

```
     aaad00101-0
     aaad00101-2
     aaad00102-0
     aaad00103-0
     aaad00404-0
```

My code is showing max value with minimum value like top two results. But I want if max value is showing then it should not show minimum value in results.

Let me know what I am missing here.
Thanks

**Fixed It:**

SQL Query:

```
   "SELECT * FROM $company WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(id)FROM
    $company GROUP BY sys_id) ORDER BY sys_id";
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want a little? I'm a bit confused by your question, but it seems like an easy fix if you could word it better maybe. Perhaps show the result set you want by typing it manually or making a sqlfiddle link?

Comment: Do you need to get the max renewal by sys_id? If yes, just do this: 
SELECT MAX(renewal), sys_id FROM $company GROUP BY sys_id;

Comment: @user2278120 I want to show single row record with having same sys_id. But I need latest entry using renewal column not the first one. That's why I am selecting max(renewal). Hope you understand what I am trying to describe.

Comment: @AntoineStas if I go with your solution I will get only two columns but I need all columns to show record.

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct that you want to keep all the rows you currently have in your table with an additional column that shows the max renewal value for each sys_id?

It's something frequently done in a window function, but since MySQL doesn't currently have that capability you can get around it with an additional join.

SELECT a.*, 
       b.last_renewal 
FROM company AS a 
     JOIN ( SELECT sys_id, 
                   MAX( renewal ) AS last_renewal 
            FROM company 
            GROUP BY sys_id ) AS b USING ( sys_id ) ;

Or are you looking for a renewal value for the latest occurrence, which I assume is for the max value of the id column?

If that's the case, you can concatenate all of the renewal values into a list and order that list by id, and then you can take out the last value in that list.

SELECT sys_id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( renewal ORDER BY id ),',',-1 ) AS last_renewal,
       MAX( id ) AS last_occurance
FROM company
GROUP BY sys_id ;

Comment: your top query fetching the result but now giving me renewals error and other column and your second query getting duplicate entries.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "renewals error"? Also, what do you mean by "duplicate entries" in the second query? It's grouped by sys_id so that column will not have a duplicate.

Comment: I have a table in which I am grouping rows by sys_id column so I will not see any duplicate entries. But with that I need the latest entry by the column renewal which decide by numbers 1 2 3 that which one is latest. For now in my query it is showing the oldest 0 and latest entry 2. But I need just latest entry 2 not the oldest entry 0. Please have a look up in results and hope you will see what I am saying.